# trouble with onbeforeunload in conjunction with confirm

Tags: javascript

I've written some code that's supposed to fire a confirm dialog box when a user leaves the page. If the user provides confirmation, a popup window is supposed to appear; otherwise, it shouldn't. However, the onbeforeunload bit isn't firing—I don't understand why. As it's probably apparent, I'm kind of a JavaScript newbie.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (confirm("Would you like to take a short survey?")) {
        w = 1000;
        h = 1000;
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        window.open('http://www.google.com','toolbar=0,resizable = 1, scrollbars = 1, width='+w+',height='+h+', top ='+top+', left='+left);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that the `onbeforeunload` wasn't fired, some browsers [block all prompts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes) in `onbeforeunload` handler, hence there's nothing to execute in your function.

Comment: @Teemu, what do you recommend as a work-around?

Comment: Provide a link to the survey on the page, if visitors want to leave a page, let them do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.

Source: [developer.mozilla.org](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

The function should return the text to be displayed in the confirm dialog:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'You are leaving this page.';
};
```

but it will not necessarily work in all browsers.

Comment: I see. The developer documentation on Mozilla's websites suggests using addEventListener in conjunction with beforeunload, so something like this?
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function() { //code});

Comment: Yes, you can find examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload